# Jmeter, jenkins and blazemeter to rag, pass/fail and rank the performance of a build

Tags: performance, jenkins, continuous-integration, jmeter, blazemeter

I am looking to use Blazemeter, JMeter and Jenkins together. I have set up a JMeter test that allows me to use Blazemeter to view the results online.

The plan is, to trigger the JMeter tests to run for every build in our continuous integration environment.

My requirements are :

1. I want to be able to see historical trend of results such as the 95th percentile response time for each JMeter test for each build. This would be usdeful in terms of some sort of bar graph.. is there a plugin out there that will do this.. or am I going to have to write something bespoke?
2. I want to be able to RAG each page response time (e.g. mark as red, amber or green based on the response time for a page). This would help me say, "login has gone red.. what changed to make this happen..."

Eventually ... 3. I want to fail a build if the RAG statuses pass a certain threshold (I would not expect to use JMeter errors to do this as I do not get errors when the page takes longer to load..)

Hope you can point me at the right resources. I went through all 160 odd articles on Blazemeter.com and have googled away.. no luck yet!

Will

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a plugin:
The [BlazeMeter Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlazeMeter+Plugin)

It will enable you to specify thresholds for error percentage (which you don't need), and response time (which you do), that will cause the build to pass (green), to be called unstable (yellow), or to fail (red).

In every build you will be able to specify a BlazeMeter test, and thus schedule tests to run whenever your build does.

You will be able to see the results of the test in the report that will be generated inside Jenkins, and view the trend and all historical data of the same test there.

This report and all others will also be waiting for you on the BlazeMeter site.
For installation and usage instructions see this video:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/102721-blazemeter-plugin-to-jenkins

I hope this helps.